# Apache Pig process CSV with fields wrapped in quotes

Tags: java, csv, apache-pig

How I can process CSV file where some fields are wrapped in quotes?

Line to process for example (field delimiter is ',')

> I am column1, I am column2, "yes, I'm am column3"

The example has three columns. But the following example will say that I have four columns:

> A = load '/path/to/file' using PigStorage(',');

Please, any suggestions, link to resource..?

Comment: Try [org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVLoader](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/CSVLoader.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the data, then do a FOREACH GENERATE to regenerate the data into whatever format you need.  For the fields where you need to remove the quotes, use a REPLACE($3, '\"').

```
data = LOAD 'testdata' USING PigStorage(",");
data = FOREACH data GENERATE
    (chararray) $0                AS col1:chararray,
    (chararray) $1                AS col2:chararray,
    (chararray) REPLACE($3, '\"') AS col3:chararray);
```

Comment: It's a not solution because Pig will define four columns instead of three. For example, column =  "yes, I'm am column3" is a two columns if PigStorage(",") is used;