# how to upload csv data with double quotes using CSVLoader or CSVExcelStoragein pig

Tags: csv, hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

I have a csv file containing following fields tweetid tweets and userid in this format e.g 1234,"hello, my name is abc",abc_123 . could anyone please help me how to upload the data in pig using CSVLoader or CSVExcelStorage?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17718357/apache-pig-process-csv-with-fields-wrapped-in-quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
a = load '<path>/<name>.csv' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage();
dump a;
```

Output :

```
(1234,"hello, my name is abc",abc_123)
```